# Elasticsearch limit the number of nested objects returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have a `user` model that has an array of `articles` objects. When I try to load a user with an `ID`, the process takes long since it could be thousands of article objects in the array. What I'm trying to do is to load only 100 nested articles. I'm using `Elasticsearch 1.5` (Old because it is hosted on AWS) , `ES Persistence gem` and `Ruby on Rails`

Tried some Docs but none worked, for example
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html

```
class User
  include Elasticsearch::Persistence::Model

  attribute :articles, Array[MiniArticle], mapping: { type: 'nested'}
  attribute :since_id
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve what you want is to use `inner_hits` but it's not supported yet out of the box.

There is a [pending pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/pull/321/files) that aims at adding support for nested `inner_hits`, but it has yet to be merged.

More info [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/320)

Comment: Do you need more info?

Comment: Thanks @Val is there a work around without using the PR? As I mentioned I'm using version 1.5 on AWS